# Calculating last years current week starting date and ending date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to calculate last years starting day of the "current week NOW()" and the ending day of that week. Along with this I am needing an offset as sometimes the Starting day of the week may not be Sunday or Monday, but even possibly a Thursday.

If a week starts on a Tuesday for instance it will end on a Monday. Given this if the current day is Thursday I need to be able to calculate the Tuesday and Monday.

I understand how to get last years current day.

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

But with the offset requirement here I am having issues calculating the starting day of that week and ending day of that week. Which needs to be in a "date format."

*** Working to clarify this more... My example was off...

***Edit

For the sake of argument (and example), let's say that today is Jan 23, 2012. My task is to accept that date and return the start and end dates for that week of the previous year.

My assumptions are:

```
1) a week is defined as having a thursday (ie 2011 week 1 is 1/2 - 1/8)
2) start of week is Sunday
```

According to the week numbering scheme as I understand it with the above assumptions, week 1 is the first week with a Thursday. That means, Jan 23 falls within week 4 in 2012. This is confirmed with `WEEK('2012-01-04') = 4`. My target thus is to select the start and end dates of week 4 of the previous year. In 2011, the results would be Jan 23 - Jan 29.

Complicating this further is then to adjust the start of the week (modify assumption 2). Continue to use WK4... 2011, Jan 23 - Jan 29, Sun - Sat, If I say the start of the week is Monday, then I would adjusting the dates by one... giving Jan 24 - Jan 30.  Tues adjusts by 2... Jan 25 - Jan 31, etc.

The approach is two steps:
    1) calculate the start and end of the *true* year week
    2) slide it into the "future" by whatever the start day would be

While the sliding into the future may or may not be correct, it would at least yield consistent results based on the conventional understanding of what "week 4" means.

Unfortunately PHP is not necessarily an option here. We need this to be ran inside of a SELECT START_WEEK, END_WEEK;

Any advice or help towards solving this query would be much helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, it's really not clear what you are looking for here. Can you please explain what you mean by different weeks having different starting days? Also, give some examples. Like if today's date is 2012-01-25, what should the query return?

Comment: I'm also not certain enough to provide an answer, though from what I can tell you might be better using PHP (or whatever language you use) to calculate the dates to then query MySQL with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week) assumes:

1. a week is defined as having a Thu
2. the start of a week is Mon

Jan 23 falls within week 4 of 2012 which you can confirm with

```
SELECT WEEK('2012-01-23', 3) = 4;
```

Week 4 of 2012 is Jan 23 to Jan 29 which you can confirm with the calendar at [whatweekisit.com](http://whatweekisit.com/). As a query, you can calculate with:

```
SELECT
    WEEK('2012-01-23', 3) AS weekNumber,
    DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK('2012-01-23') - 2 DAY) AS startOfWeek,
    DATE_ADD('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 8 - DAYOFWEEK('2012-01-23') DAY) as endOfWeek;
```

Week 4 of 2011 is Jan 24 to Jan 30 (also confirmable by calendar). It is true that same date may not fall within the current week number and last year's week, but I don't suspect they would be wildly different.

```
SELECT
    IF (WEEK('2012-01-23', 3) = WEEK(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), 3),
        DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) - 2 DAY),
        DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) - 2 DAY)) AS datetimeStart;
```

Notice that I'm always representing the calculations verbatim in several places (e.g. `DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` of Jan 32 2011); if you're doing this within a stored procedure or UDF you can probably use variables to make it more concise/readable/maintainable.

Now that the start and end of the target year week has been identified, you can simply apply your offset. Given `$weekDayStart` is 0 - 6 (Sun - Sat):

```
SELECT
    DATE_ADD(
        IF (WEEK('2012-01-23', 3) = WEEK(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), 3),
            DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) - 2 DAY),
            DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) - 2 DAY)),
        INTERVAL $weekDayStart - 1 DAY) AS datetimeStart,

    DATE_ADD(
        IF (WEEK('2012-01-23', 3) = WEEK(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), 3),
            DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) - 2 DAY),
            DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR), INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD('2012-01-23', INTERVAL 6 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) - 2 DAY)), 
        INTERVAL $weekDayStart + 5 DAY) AS datetimeEnd;
```

So, working it through with the input of 2012-01-23 and start day of Thurs would yield:

1. **Jan 23 2012** = week 4
2. week 4 of 2011 = 1/24-1/30
3. Offset Thu - Mon (4 - 1) is +3 which moves window to **Jan 27 - Feb 2 2011**

Answer (score 0):

Found it... Had to read up on the issue a little more. 
This ended up being 7 different queries.

My Base Query:

```
Sunday Start Day of Week
SELECT 
DATE_SUB(
DATE_ADD( 
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR('2012-01-04')-1, '-01-01' ), '%Y-%m-%d'), #Get last year starting date. 
INTERVAL WEEK('2012-01-04') WEEK),
INTERVAL 6 DAY) START_DAY_OF_WEEK,
DATE_ADD( 
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR('2012-01-04')-1, '-01-01' ), '%Y-%m-%d'),
INTERVAL WEEK('2012-01-04') WEEK) END_DAY_OF_WEEK;
```

This gets me Week 1 of 2011. Starting of that week is 1/2 and ending on 1/8. 
Now if my week starts on a different day I add in an offset...

```
Tuesday Start Day of Week
SELECT 
DATE_SUB(
DATE_ADD( 
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR('2012-01-04')-1, '-01-01' ), '%Y-%m-%d'), #Get last year starting date. 
INTERVAL WEEK('2012-01-04') WEEK),
INTERVAL 4 DAY) START_DAY_OF_WEEK,
DATE_ADD(
DATE_ADD( 
STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( YEAR('2012-01-04')-1, '-01-01' ), '%Y-%m-%d'), #Get last year starting date. 
INTERVAL WEEK('2012-01-04') WEEK),
INTERVAL 2 DAY) END_DAY_OF_WEEK;
```

This will give me 1/4 start day of week and ending on 1/10.

To get the other days of the week is relatively simple:

- Sunday (First Query...)
- Monday -5 start day +1 end day.
- Tuesday -4 start day +2 end day.
- Wednesday -3 start day +3 end day.
- Thursday -2 start day -4 end day.
- Friday -1 start day -5 end day.
- Saturday -0 start day -6 end day.

It is 7 separate queries but does enable me to do what I was intending to do.